# Getting Undefined When Passing Function From An Object As Callback Within Another Function From Same Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, undefined, arrow-functions

I'm not knowledgeable in JS and JS in Node RTE. But I tried writing simple functions as arrow functions in objects for later usage. One of these arrow functions (data.volatile.modularVariables.read) calls the readFile (asynchronous) function from FileSystem node native module, and passes the following into the parameters from the same object:

1. file path (data.persistent.paths.srcRoot)
2. encoding scheme (data.volatile.modularVariables.encoding.utf8)
3. call-back function (data.volatile.modularVariables.readCB) <-issue lays here

relevant Code (the object):

```
var data = 
{
    persistent:
    {
        states:
        {
            //exempt for question clarity
        },
        paths:
        {
            srcRoot: './vortex/root.txt'
        }
    },
    volatile:
    {
        //much of the data exempt for question clarity
        modularVariables:
        {
            encoding: {utf8:'utf8',hex:'hex',base64:'base64',BIN:(data,encoding)=>{Buffer.from(data,encoding)}},
            readCB: (err,data)=>{if(err){console.log(`%c${data.volatile.debug.debugStrings.errCodes.read}: Error reading from file`,'color: red'); console.log(data);}},
            writeCB: (err)=>{if(err){console.log(`%c${data.volatile.debug.debugStrings.errCodes.write}: Error writing to file`, 'color:red')}},
            read: (file,encoding,cb)=>{fs.readFile(file,encoding,cb)}, //cb = readCB  READ file srcRoot, pass into root(rootHash,encoding)
            write: (file,data,cb)=>{fs.writeFile(file,data,cb)}, //cb = writeCB
            checkInit: (symbol)=>{if(typeof symbol !== undefined){return symbol}} 
        },
        debug: 
        {
            functions:
            {
                append: 
                {
                    testProg:{program:{main:'system.node.upgrade'}}
                }
            },
            debugStrings:
            {
                errCodes:
                {
                    read: 'AFTERNET ERR 000',
                    write: 'AFTERNET ERR 001',
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Aggregator Code:

```
    testing()
    {
        data.volatile.modularVariables.read(data.persistent.paths.srcRoot,data.volatile.modularVariables.encoding.utf8,data.volatile.modularVariables.readCB(data));
    };
```

Terminal Error:

```
readCB: (err,data)=>{if(err){console.log(`%c${data.volatile.debug.debugStrings.errCodes.read}: Error reading from file`,'color: red'); console.log(data);}},
                                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'volatile' of undefined
```

Notes:

- In aggregator code, I tried not passing "data" into callback
- I tried passing "err" but says it's undefined
- I tried not passing anything into CB

Conclusion:

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong and why?

Comment: Hou have to insert your data definition before your testing() function. Could be this the problem. Try it

Comment: my data object is written before testing function. (If that is what you meant, pardon my ignorance if it was not). Although, data object is outside scope of the class "testing" function is in if that makes any difference?

Comment: Yes,if the object `data` is initialized after, you will not have an error because a `var` variable is hoisted but it will be `undefined`. If isn't the case, inside testing() data will be visible ant with the right value, and the problem will be another. To be sure you ca do a `console.log(data)` inside the testing() function to verify if `data` is an object or is undefined

Comment: it can indeed be read as ```{
  persistent: {
    states: { wormholes: [LevelUP], singularity: [LevelUP] },
    paths: { srcRoot: './vortex/root.txt' }
  },
  volatile: {
    modularVariables: {
      encoding: [Object],
      root: [Function: root],
      createTrie: [Function: createTrie],
      readCB: [Function: readCB],
      writeCB: [Function: writeCB],
      read: [Function: read],
      write: [Function: write],
      checkInit: [Function: checkInit]
    },
    debug: { functions: [Object], debugStrings: [Object] }
  }
}``` I should have stringified it

Comment: By the way, thank you for your time. Your help means a lot to me bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't tell from the comments if you've resolved the error, but I have a few suggestions that may help.

---

### Aggregator Code

I noticed that you are sending the [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) in that code and passing in the `data` object, which is assigned to the `err` argument and the `data` argument will be undefined:

```js
testing() {
  data.volatile.modularVariables.read(
    data.persistent.paths.srcRoot,
    data.volatile.modularVariables.encoding.utf8,
    data.volatile.modularVariables.readCB(data)
  );
}
```

When passing in the callback function, you only need to specify the callback function name as below. NodeJS will call the callback with the appropriate `err` and `data` arguments. I believe this should resolve your problem.

```js
testing() {
  data.volatile.modularVariables.read(
    data.persistent.paths.srcRoot,
    data.volatile.modularVariables.encoding.utf8,
    data.volatile.modularVariables.readCB
  );
}
```

---

### Variable Naming

One thing that could help others read your code and spot issues without needing to run the code is making sure you don't have variables with the same name. I believe you are attempting to reference your `data` object outside of the callback function, but in the scope of the callback function, `data` will be primarily referenced as the argument passed in (see [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)). When I ran your code, the debugger showed me that `data` was undefined before applying the fix above. After, it showed me that `data` was an empty string.

For this, you can either change your `data` object to be named something like `myData` or `cypherData` and it will not conflict with any of your other variables/parameters.

---

### Full Solution

```js
var cypherData = {
  persistent: {
    states: {
      //exempt for question clarity
    },
    paths: {
      srcRoot: "./vortex/root.txt"
    }
  },
  volatile: {
    //much of the data exempt for question clarity
    modularVariables: {
      encoding: {
        utf8: "utf8",
        hex: "hex",
        base64: "base64",
        BIN: (data, encoding) => {
          Buffer.from(data, encoding);
        }
      },
      readCB: (err, data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (err) {
          console.log(
            `%c${data.volatile.debug.debugStrings.errCodes.read}: Error reading from file`,
            "color: red"
          );
        }
      },
      writeCB: (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(
            `%c${data.volatile.debug.debugStrings.errCodes.write}: Error writing to file`,
            "color:red"
          );
        }
      },
      read: (file, encoding, cb) => {
        fs.readFile(file, encoding, cb);
      }, //cb = readCB  READ file srcRoot, pass into root(rootHash,encoding)
      write: (file, data, cb) => {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, cb);
      }, //cb = writeCB
      checkInit: (symbol) => {
        if (typeof symbol !== undefined) {
          return symbol;
        }
      }
    },
    debug: {
      functions: {
        append: {
          testProg: { program: { main: "system.node.upgrade" } }
        }
      },
      debugStrings: {
        errCodes: {
          read: "AFTERNET ERR 000",
          write: "AFTERNET ERR 001"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
cypherData.volatile.modularVariables.read(
  cypherData.persistent.paths.srcRoot,
  cypherData.volatile.modularVariables.encoding.utf8,
  cypherData.volatile.modularVariables.readCB
);
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it. However, I am still getting an empty string in-spite of renaming my "data" object to programData. It is quite late for me, I hope perhaps I did not miss anything in your reply as I am going to sleep on my keyboard any moment now haha.

Comment: The program finishes with no bugs, but it doesn't console log the data parameter (the data being read from the file) in my call-back for read arrow function which is odd.

Comment: Hmm... I reviewed your original code and comparing it to mine and couldn't find anything that hasn't been suggested. I created a file in `./vortex/` named `root.txt` and added a sentence. Then, I tested it with NodeJS and it returned the sentence in the file with the `console.log(data)` in the callback. Double-check that the `root.txt` file is not empty.